# Запятая перед союзом как

Tags: как, пунктуация

Вместе делать нельзя, как, например, в том-то

Comment: @Dino, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна. После союза "как" стоит вводное слово.

Answer (score 0):

1. Отношения включения без присоединительного оттенка выражаются

   > устойчивыми
   > сочетаниями как например, такие как, а также (редко) союзом как; при этом
   > второй член всегда имеет форму им. п.: Совершенно посторонние люди, как 
   > Ершовы,
   > оказали нам самое горячее участие (В. Поленов); Первые азиатские революции
   > произошли не в колониях, а в полуколониальных странах, таких как Иран, 
   > Турция и
   > Китай (газ.); По предметам крестьянского быта, как например туесок из 
   > бересты
   > или прялка, легко узнать сибирскую деревню (газ.).<br />
   > Этот третий случай - из "Русской грамматики" на сайте http: 
   > rusgram.narod.ru